# cannot change the color of tableviewcell when it is selected

Tags: ios, uitableview

i am new to iOS. i am using gradient in my tableview. I can change the color using gradient when table view is loaded. But i cannot change the color of tableview cell when it is selected. I did not use custom cell. Please help me. thanks in advance

Comment: How are you adding the gradient to the cell?

Comment: you have blue or grey color

Comment: Did you load gradient image or CAGradientLayer?

Comment: i have added the gradient as mentioned below in cellforrowatindexpath                                        gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
gradient.frame = CGRectMake(0,0, 100, 61);
            m_gradientContact.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)UIColorFromRGB(0XFEFEFE).CGColor, (id)UIColorFromRGB(0XBCBCBC).CGColor, nil];
[cell.contentView.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];

Answer (score 1):

When developing for iOS 7, you have to define the background view for your cells if you don't want the standard one.

In your method `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, do :

```
UIView *bgColorView = [[UIView alloc] init];
bgColorView.backgroundColor = /* your customized color */ ;
bgColorView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
cell.selectedBackgroundView = bgColorView;
```

when creating your cells.

Comment: This is correct, I'm using the same technique and it's working

Comment: thanks for your help. Its working in background, but i want to change the color of a particular cell when is tapped.i want to implement it using gradient.

Comment: Do you want to change its color definitively, or just for the selected row(s) ?

Comment: for selected rows color should be changed

Answer (score 0):

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

```
CAGradientLayer *grad = [CAGradientLayer layer];
grad.frame = cell.bounds;
grad.colors = [desired colors]

[cell setBackgroundView:[[UIView alloc] init]];
[cell.backgroundView.layer insertSublayer:grad atIndex:0];

CAGradientLayer *selectedGrad = [CAGradientLayer layer];
selectedGrad.frame = cell.bounds;
selectedGrad.colors = desired colors

[cell setSelectedBackgroundView:[[UIView alloc] init]];
[cell.selectedBackgroundView.layer insertSublayer:selectedGrad atIndex:0];
```

}